# Translating time of day to fr-CA in .net - wrong short time format string?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

We are in the process of translating our WPF application to fr-CA. Certain screens in the application display times using the 't' standard time specifier:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding MyTimeValue, StringFormat=' {0:t}'}" ></TextBlock>
```

In the fr-ca culture, this produces the string "HH:mm" (as in 11:00). However, our translator insists that we should display the time as "HH \h mm" (as in 11 h 00).

Based on some other SO questions and answers, I looked at `DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` which returns a list of all "standard" patterns for a given culture. I see that the desired format string *does* appear in that list. But how do I programatically select that one without prior knowledge of where to find it? I don't want to have to write custom code to support showing a time just for fr-ca.

Comment: can you not just set the culture..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms788718(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Write your own culture and pass it in.

Comment: we are setting the culture to fr-ca. That's not the issue. The issue is that the standard ShortTimePattern for fr-ca seems to be "HH:mm" and not "HH \h mm" as our translator insists.

Comment: if you insist on using a format which is not the default for the given culture, you will have no other option than to write custom code. There is literally nothing which differentiates this format from all the others, save your translator's whim.

Comment: Maybe an off-topic comment, but how old is this translator? My reading of the answer provided below sounds like the powers that be in Quebec have decided to move with the times and conform to an international standard. But older people have a tendency to resist change, and demand that things be done the way they were taught when they went to school, and that they've done all their lives.

Comment: There are too many variations in common use in Canada.  Microsoft picked one of them.  You can't win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extract of the "Caractéristiques culturelles et linguistiques du Québec"

8. Les heures
   La période de 24 heures constitue
   la base de référence pour la présentation numérique de 
   l'heure
   ,
   conformément à la norme
   ISO 8601:2000
   . L'indication de l'heure est suivie de celle
   des minutes, les
   deux éléments étant séparés par les deux points 
   (sans e
   s
   p
   a
   ce).
   Exemple : 17:30 (et non
   5 h 30 P.M., qui correspond à l'usage américain)

A quick translation, that means that inserting the "h" after the hours, corresponds to the american usage for showing time.

Document can be found [here](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/ti/dossiers/CCLQTI_20040720.pdf)

Comment: We don't spell that way around here.  It probably intents to say "American word order".

Comment: @HansPassant: I think the bit about American usage refers to the am/pm part, not the "h". Plus maybe a bit of "if you don't do it the way we say, we'll accuse you of imitating the Americans, and you don't want that, do you?"

Comment: I'm not a translator, Bones, I'm a developer :P